# Angular - Template driven form - Email validation not happening

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I am making a simple template-driven form with 'Email Validation' in it (Not by Reactive Forms). So, required, minlength, maxlength are working fine. But, when I try email to be valid, its failing. Can someone help me out?

**abc.component.html**

```
  <form #customForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="alpha(customForm)">

    <input type="text" name="firstName" ngModel #firstName ="ngModel" required minlength="3" maxlength="10"><br/>

    <div *ngIf="firstName.touched">
      <p *ngIf="firstName.errors?.required">First Name is Required!!!</p>
      <p *ngIf="firstName.errors?.minlength">First Name minimum 3 characters are required!!!</p>
      <p *ngIf="firstName.errors?.maxlength">First Name max length is 10!!!</p>
    </div>

    <input type="email" name="email" ngModel #email="ngModel" required><br/>

    <div *ngIf="email.touched">
      <p *ngIf="email.errors?.required">Email is a required field!</p>
      <p *ngIf="email.errors?.email">This is not a valid Email!!!</p>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="customForm.invalid">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

> **Note:** Though required validation of email is taking place, but as the
>   pattern or data entered is not correct, ***the 2nd validation*** in email
>   validation div must give error.

**Result:** (Email valid and its pattern not automatically giving error)

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could add an `email` attribute to your Email Input. But then that would not in-validate it for something of the pattern `xxx@xxx` which I think would not be a valid email in your case.

I suggest you use `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"` instead. Then, where you're showing the error message, you should check for `email.errors?.pattern` instead.

Give this a try:

```
<input 
  type="email" 
  name="email" 
  ngModel 
  #email="ngModel" 
  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" 
  required>
<br/>

<div *ngIf="email.touched">
  <p *ngIf="email.errors?.required">Email is a required field!</p>
  <p *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern">This is not a valid Email!!!</p>
</div>
```

Try both the approaches on this [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-validation-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) and use the one that suits you better.

Comment: Yes, pattern works. But why not like 'Reactive-Forms' just error.email is generated (I saw the same while working with reactive forms -- we don't need to give pattern. It provides error simply as errors.email without giving pattern).

Comment: Because we're not using the `email` attribute like you've used `required`. We're using `pattern`

Comment: yes, you're right. Adding only 'email' attribute -- validates abc.abc as correct email which is definitely wrong. Pattern is the better solution. @saadMehmood got a good answer, but your's seems better and validates all mails correctly.

Comment: I would be very cautious using a regex pattern to validate emails, especially with all the new top-level domains available these days. For example, guy@met.museum wouldn't be valid with the example regex provided here.

Answer (score 24):

Replace this line

```
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel #email="ngModel" required>
```

with

```
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel #email="ngModel" required email>// add email attribute
```

Comment: @Deadpool,  try this approach for `something@something` even that would be valid if you use this. Do you accept such emails as valid in your case. If yes, sure, go for this one?

Answer (score 0):

use "pattern = regrex" in input tag and use validation email?.errors?.pattern